# How to split a string in angular HTML And Also How To Create Custom split() PipeTransform In Angular and TypeScript

Tags: angular, string, typescript, split

How to split a string in angular HTML **Angular Interpolation Data Binding**

Comment: If this should be a problem+solution, then please separate problem and solution (and post the solution as an answer). If it is a question, what's the question?

Comment: Where is the question? write your articles in CodeProject.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Angular and TypeScript To Create A Custom split() Pipe

**NG Command** to Create A Pipe
Type this command in **Command Prompt**

```
ng g pipe pipes/split
```

**ng** means Angular

**g** means Generate

**pipes** means folder name

**split** means pipe name

Code For Custom split() use this code in
**(split.pipe.ts)**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'split'
})

export class SplitPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(text: string, by: string, index: number = 1) {
    let arr = text.split(by);
    return arr[index]
  }
}
```

HTML Code use this code in
**(example.component.html)**

```
<h5>{{ data.helloWorld | split:"/":1 }}</h5>
```